# Unable to load firebase Init provider - android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I cant solve this bug for many days. It happens only when I connect firebase realtime database.

```
Process: com.bae.dialogflowbot, PID: 4982
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~RkMsTUa-PZYOQLsQ7fP8Uw==/com.bae.dialogflowbot-m8QxV2lnB1WTxOUZJ-hy0w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~RkMsTUa-PZYOQLsQ7fP8Uw==/com.bae.dialogflowbot-m8QxV2lnB1WTxOUZJ-hy0w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[**[zip file "/data/app/~~RkMsTUa-PZYOQLsQ7fP8Uw==/com.bae.dialogflowbot-m8QxV2lnB1WTxOUZJ-hy0w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~RkMsTUa-PZYOQLsQ7fP8Uw==/com.bae.dialogflowbot-m8QxV2lnB1WTxOUZJ-hy0w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, i didnt. i went to flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seemed to work. Go to your gradle and comment out this line:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
```

Use this one:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
```

I had FMS working on one project and tried to fold it back into another, but got the same error. After a bunch of unsuccessful searches, I tried making changes to each setting to mirror the first project and this one seemed to work.